# WPF SelectedItem from one ListView and show Relational Data in the other LsitView

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, listview, data-binding, mvvm

I'm creating a WPF application, allowing a user to enter in details using `CRUD` operation using `Entity Framework` (also using a Repository pattern).

So far, I've created an Application that allows a user to enter a *Prospect* client. I am able to edit this *Prospect*, add a new one and able to delete with ease.

This *Prospect* though has a `Foreign Key` relation within another table known as *ProspectMeeting*, taking the `ProspectID` from the *Prospect* table.

When I `Select` a *Prospect* from the `ListView` though, it doesn't show the data of that selected *Prospect*.

The Image below is the image of the application in its current state - So hope that gives a better understanding of what I want to achieve.

[image]

In my repository I use this to get a `List` of *ProspectMeetings* using the ProspectID;

```
    public List<ProspectMeeting> GetMeetingByProspect(int _ProspectID)
    {
        using (var context = new DBEntities())
        {
            return context.Prospects.First(i => i.ProspectID == _ProspectID).ProspectMeetings.ToList();
        }
    }
```

In my *ProspectViewModel*, I use this `Observable Collection` to get the data from the *ProspectMeetingViewModel*;

```
    private ObservableCollection<ProspectMeetingViewModel> prospectMeetings = null;
    public ObservableCollection<ProspectMeetingViewModel> ProspectMeetings
    {
        get { return GetProspectMeetings(); }
        set
        {
            prospectMeetings = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProspectMeetings");
        }
    }

    internal ObservableCollection<ProspectMeetingViewModel> GetProspectMeetings()
    {
        ProspectMeetingRepository c = new ProspectMeetingRepository();
        prospectMeetings = new ObservableCollection<ProspectMeetingViewModel>();
        prospectMeetings.Clear();

        foreach (DataObjects.ProspectMeeting i in c.GetMeetingByProspect(this.ProspectID))
        {
            ProspectMeetingViewModel prospectMeeting = new ProspectMeetingViewModel(i);
            prospectMeeting.Prospect = this;
            prospectMeetings.Add(prospectMeeting);
        }
        return prospectMeetings;
    }
```

And in my *ProspectListViewModel*;

```
    private ProspectListViewModel() : base("")
    {
        this.ProspectList = GetProspects();
    }

    private ProspectViewModel selectedProspect = null;
    public ProspectViewModel SelectedProspect
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedProspect;
        }
        set
        {
            selectedProspect = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedProspect");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ProspectViewModel> prospectList = null;
    public ObservableCollection<ProspectViewModel> ProspectList
    {
        get
        {
            return GetProspects();
        }
        set
        {
            prospectList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProspectList");
        }
    }

    internal ObservableCollection<ProspectViewModel> GetProspects()
    {
        if (prospectList == null)
            prospectList = new ObservableCollection<ProspectViewModel>();
        prospectList.Clear();

        foreach (DataObjects.Prospect i in new ProspectRepository().GetAll())
        {
            ProspectViewModel c = new ProspectViewModel(i);
            prospectList.Add(c);
        }
        return prospectList;
    }
```

I've been following this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/332615/WPF-Master-Details-MVVM-Application) to help me but I've become unstuck. Personally, When I look through my code, I think that it has something to do with the Repository not getting the data. But I am not too sure.

I hope some one could advice or me or help me with this issue. Firstly, sorry if this is a long question to take in and secondly if more code needs to be added then just let me know, I only added the data that I thought was appropriate.

Thanks in advance :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in the end was a binding issue. In my *MainWindow.xaml* i didn't assign the *ProspectMeetingListView* to the `SelectedProspect`, like so;

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ProspectMeetingListTemplate" >
        <v:ProspectMeetingListView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Content="{Binding SelectedProspect}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ProspectMeetingListTemplate}" />
```

Silly mistake from my behalf.